# Loop using csv values to call API using pentaho, each number in the body of each call, 300 times

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

pls, I have a transformation running ok, it calls a Rest Api via POST.

But now I have to, dinamically, in the body of the call, change one value at a time to call it with a new number read from a csv.

What I have so far:

Generate rows -> REST Client -> Json input -> Add sequence -> Select values -> Table Output

My Generate rows is (it defines the body of the call):

{"AutheticationToken": {"Username": "INT.ODONTO","Password": "123456","EnvironmentName": "ODONTO"},"Data": {"Fornecedor":"040001000117"}}

What I need is to change "Data": {"Fornecedor":"040001000117"} into "Data": {"Fornecedor":"${variable}"} or something and loop using each of the 300 numbers I have in a csv.

How to do it?

Much appreciated, tyvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two transformations and a job.

In the job you put a first transformation reading the csv and outputting the column with variable in the result (use the *Copy rows to result* step).

The second transformation is your transformation, modifying the Generate rows step to use something that allows receiving an argument or a parameter to build the call to the REST client with the values passed from the previous transformation. The trick to allow passing the values from the first transformation to the second is in the job, you edit the properties of the second transformation checking the property *Execute for every input row?* and, if you are using arguments in the transformation, mark the check *Copy previous results to args?*, if you are using variables, map the variable to name of the column in the previous transformation.

You have an example using arguments in the samples directory in your PDI installation: **samples/jobs/shell for every row**.